# How can I use Github secrets in JS files

Tags: javascript, bash, github, yaml, github-actions

I have a basic git repo set up with github actions to build and deploy (HTML and TS files mainly).

However I have to use in some API Keys that needs to be secret.

So I figure out to use GITHUB SECRETS for them.

How can I access GITHUB SECRETS in my js (or TS) files so it can build with github actions properly?

Comment: @imjared nop, my question is specific to github secrets. I know how secrets are working, I just want to know how to use them properly with github and github actions

Comment: You can't use secrets in files as an environment variable, secrets can be only used for Github Actions

Comment: @AhmetZeybek Yes but their might be a way to create a env file during the action build process with batch and insert them on it right ?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env

Comment: @AhmetZeybek already read that, but not working in my case, need something like run: echo "export const environment = { firebase_api_key : ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}" > env/env.ts but get yaml error

Comment: There is a difference between github actions and github workflow. Are you asking about accessing secrets in a custom github action built by yourself, or in a workflow?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can pass-in Secrets as ENV variables.

**Example:**

```
   ...
   steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node 12.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x

      - name: Install Dependencies (prod)
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production

      - name: Run Tests (JEST)
        run: yarn test --ci --silent --testPathIgnorePatterns=experimental
        env:
          CI: true
          API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
```

In Node.js you can access it via `process.env.API_KEY`.

Comment: @antoinehervet I edited my answer with the usage via Node.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code snippet. FYI, you no longer need to set `CI: true`, [see here](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-15-github-actions-sets-the-ci-environment-variable-to-true/) for details

Answer (score 2):

I Find a way to achieve it although it might not be the best (And I'm definitly not bash expert)

So create a setEnv.sh file

```
mkdir env
echo "export const environment = { firebase_api_key : '$1' }"  > env/env.ts
```

That take as your API key as first parameter, create a env folder and save TS code with your api key.

Then add this line

```
- run: sh setEnvironment.sh ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
```

Into your github action script, which will execute your script and set the Secret Key.

You'll now just have to use `environment.firebase_api_key` in your code.

---

**Note:** Your build needs to encrypt your key otherwise it will be exposed. But this can be usefull for example if you use API keys on your website and you also want your website code to be available in public on Github, without those plain keys.

Answer (score 1):

I created an action exactly for that - takes all the secrets and exports them to environment variables.

An example would be:

```
...
- run: node -e "console.log(process.env.MY_SECRET1)"
  env:
    MY_SECRET1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET1 }}
    MY_SECRET2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET2 }}
    MY_SECRET3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET3 }}
    MY_SECRET4: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET4 }}
    MY_SECRET5: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET5 }}
    MY_SECRET6: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET6 }}
    ...
```

You could convert it to:

```
...
- uses: oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action@v1
  with:
    secrets: ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}
- run: node -e "console.log(process.env.MY_SECRET1)"
```

Link to the action, which contains more documentation about configuration: https://github.com/oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action

You should be able to use them after running the action in your JS code using `process.env.MY_SECRET1`