# NodeJS/Heroku Application Error for reading env variables with Github Action

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, github-actions, steam

Initially, I had a working git repo with a workflow setup so as to upload some NodeJS source code on a `git push` request which all worked fine. However I have a Steam API key that was in an .env file which I did not want public (removing .env altogether) so I wanted to use Github Secrets to store the **STEAM_API_KEY** (along with other variables such as **BASE_URL**) within yml env variables used in the workflow as follows:

```
jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    env: 
      BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.BASE_URL }}
      STEAM_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.STEAM_API_KEY }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Use Node.js 14.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
          
      - name: Running CI Installation
        run: npm ci
      - name: Running Application/Server Unit Tests
        run: npm test
```

I than accessed them in my code with `process.env.<variable_name>` (following [How can I use Github secrets in JS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686823/how-can-i-use-github-secrets-in-js-files)):

```
module.exports = new SteamAuth({
    realm: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/steam/user/auth`,
    returnUrl: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/steam/user/auth`,
    apiKey: process.env.STEAM_API_KEY
});
```

But throws me this error on Heroku:

> Error: Missing realm, returnURL or apiKey parameter(s). These are required.

This does not happen if I simply hard-code the strings directly into **realm**, **returnUrl** and **apiKey**.

Upon further troubleshooting:

```
    var url1 = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/steam/user/auth`; // BASE_URL = "https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com"
    var url2 = "https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/steam/user/auth";

    console.log(url1 === url2);
    console.log(url1);
    console.log(url2);
```

Outputs:

```
true
***/steam/user/auth
***/steam/user/auth
```

Where **url1** has `process.env.BASE_URL` encrypted. But **url2** gets encrypted too since it resembles BASE_URL?? Is this a *flaw* with Github Actions?

At this point I am out of ideas. I am doing something wrong but don't know where to go from here. Anyone have any idea on how to properly use Github secrets in .js code?

**PS**: Github secrets/workflows are very new to me, please be indulgent with my lack of knowledge/understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the problem out:
The env variables are only available when running the Github Action, **NOT** while executing from Heroku.

Still doesn't explain the last part tho with `url2`